# how can I find the lowest value in my array in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that calculates the highest value in my set of values:

```
var collection = [];

$histogram.find('li').each(function() {
    collection.push($(this).data());
});

component.props.collection = collection;

// Find Histogram max value
collection.hasMax = function(value) {
    return this.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        return prev[value] > curr[value] ? prev : curr;
    });
};
// Assign Max Value
component.props.maxRange = collection.hasMax('value').value;
```

I need to create a second function that does the same, but for the lowest values, e.g. the function called `hasMin`. I thought it would be enough to just change the comparision here:

```
return prev[value] < curr[value] ? prev : curr;
```

but I tested it and it didn't work, can you help me with that?

Comment: How about [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)?

Comment: @ScottMarcus is there a way of also refactoring the existing code to use the Math.max then?

Comment: You're adding a function to an array just to call it ? There are much cleaner ways... For example passing the array as argument

Comment: @DenysSéguret could you give me some example?

Comment: Sure, throw your code away and just use `console.log(Math.min(...YourArray));`

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript's built-in `Math` object has a static  **[`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)** method, which seems to solve your problem without the need for all that code you are using.

You can get the lowest value of an array by using JavaScript's **[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)** (to turn the array into a comma separated list of values) and pass that list to the method.

There's also **[`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)**.

```js
let myData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
console.log(Math.min(...myData));  
console.log(Math.max(...myData));
```

You've indicated that `collection` is an array of objects and each object has a `value` property and you need to get the lowest and highest values in that object array so this will do it:

```js
// This is just set up to emulate your data structure. Don't add this:
var sth = "test", sth2 = "test", sth3 = "test";
let component = { props: {} };
let collection = [{value:0, label: sth},{value:1, label: sth2},{value:3, label:sth3}];

// Assuming your data structure is set up, the following will get you there:

// Loop over the array of objects, extracting the value property of each object into a new array
let vals = collection.map(function(obj){ 
   return obj.value; // Place the value of each object into an array
});

// Just set your object's properties to the min and max of the destructured array
component.props.minRange = Math.min(...vals);
component.props.maxRange = Math.max(...vals);

console.log(component.props.minRange, component.props.maxRange);
```

Comment: Scott, thanks, one question though - could you show me a code snippet based on the code I submitted in the question? I need to store the max value in `component.props.maxRang` and min value in `component.props.maxRang`

Comment: @randomuser1 I've updated the answer to show this. It's just a matter of setting the property of your object to the value returned from the method(s). No loops or `if/then` needed.

Comment: I did in my case `component.props.maxRange = Math.max(collection);`however, when I print it I'm getting a `NaN` value - do you know what might be the reason of that?

Comment: @randomuser1 Is `collection` an array of numeric values?

Comment: In html I have: `<li data-label="${label}" data-value="${model.dataMap[label]}"></li>` and in js I have `$histogram.find('li').each(function() {
    collection.push($(this).data());
});`

Comment: now when I print `Math.max(collection))` I'm getting `NaN`

Comment: Thanks Scott - when I printed out the collection, I''ve got: `{value:0, label: sth}{value:1, label: sth2}{value:3, label:sth3}`

Comment: @randomuser1 That's not a valid syntax. You've listed 3 objects, one after the other. How exactly did you print those values?

Comment: i wrote `console.log(collection)` and this is what I have in developers console https://imgur.com/rvjN2sy

Answer (score 0):

with ES5:

```
let sth = "test", sth2 = "test", sth3 = "test";
let component = { props: {} };
let collection = [{value:0, label: sth},{value:1, label: sth2},{value:3, 
label:sth3}];

// Assuming your data structure is set up, the following will get you there:

// Loop over the array of objects, extracting the value property of each 
object into a new array
let vals = collection.map(function(obj){ 
   return obj.value; // Place the value of each object into an array
});

// Just set your object's properties to the min and max of the destructured array
component.props.minRange = Math.min.apply(Math,vals);
component.props.maxRange = Math.max.apply(Math,vals);

console.log(component.props.minRange, component.props.maxRange);
```

Comment: Thanks, so could you show me how exactly and where in my code should I use those return statements?

Comment: i've used  @Scott Marcus code to demonstrate how to in ES5